# persist $rootScope into directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a open/close profile view, where the user can click in anywhare to close this profile.

For now, i created a `$rootscope` variable for `ngIf` controlling.

```
// this is a toggle functionality
$rootScope.profileOpened = false;
$rootScope.userProfile = function () {
    if ($rootScope.profileOpened) {
        $rootScope.profileOpened = false;
    } else {
        $rootScope.profileOpened = true;
    }
}
```

and then i have a directive in the body to bind a click to set the `$rootScope.profileOpened` to false.

```
this.app.directive("globalEvents", function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                if ($rootScope.profileOpened) {
                    $rootScope.profileOpened = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

html directive

```
<body global-events>
```

the `$rootScope` injection in the directive is working fine, but when a manipulate the variable inside the directive, my original `$rootScope.profileOpened` dos not change, sounds like i lose my `$rootScope` reference.

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value will change but since the event is outside of angular you need to tell angular to run a digest by using `$apply()` or `$timeout()` or you won't see the changes reflected in view.

Try:

```
 element.bind('click', function (e) {
      if ($rootScope.profileOpened) {
         $rootScope.profileOpened = false;
         scope.$apply();
       }
  });
```

If you use `ng-click` angular will automatically run the digest internally.